# PhoneGap Build apps - text sizes for different screen sizes?

Tags: css, phonegap-build

This isn't an Android app question, as such, because it pertains to anything that one could build for PhoneGap Build for Android, iOS, Windows mobile, etc.

I've built an app that has text in boxes that are a % of the screen width. I'm happy with this and it seems to work fine on my GNexus, Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and Xoom.

But one of my users on a Galaxy S3 has reported a text overflow issue on his phone.

I'm using % widths for the text boxes. Should I be doing the same for my text sizes or should I use em (which I don't really get anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
<input type='text'/>
```

or

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

to display information to a user and do not intend for the user to edit/modify the text box, then you should consider using a label instead.

```
<label></label>
```

This will prevent overflow issues and allow the user to scroll to see info as long as other factors aren't preventing scrolling.

If you do need to use a 'textarea' tag then using jQuery you can do:

```
$("#yourTextAreaId").height( $("#yourTextAreaId").scrollHeight );
```

Or, if you aren't using jQuery, here is some plain JS for you:

```
var myTextArea = document.getElementByID('yourTextAreaId');
myTextArea.height = myText.scrollHeight + "px";;
```

Run either one of those samples after you have set the value of the textarea and/or any time the value of the textarea changes.